# Silenium работа с несколькими сайтами

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я произвожу действия на нескольких сайтах с помощью asyncio (ставлю таймер на повторяющиеся действие).
Мой текущий код заставляет меня каждый раз переключаться на вкладку, которая вышла из сна.
Для примера мой текущий код:

```
asynctio def parse_site_1(previous_page, target_page):
driver.switch_to.window(target_page)
await do_something()
driver.switch_to.window(previous_page)
```

Возможно ли производить действия на сайтах без переключения между сайтами (вкладками) каждый раз?

Comment: нет, нельзя. только если напрямую не юзать API напрямую с браузером

Comment: Можно, запустив 2 инстанса браузера